# Should I use an ActiveRecord has_may-through relation, or a method fetching related items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a FormResponse which `belongs_to` a Form; the Form then `has_many` Questions:

```
class FormResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :form
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :form_responses
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I find myself needing `questions` in the context of a form, a lot, I prefer to call questions on FormResponse, like so:

```
form_response = FormResponse.find(id)
form_response.questions
```

In order to make `questions` avaiable, I can do this in ActiveRecord:

```
class FormResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :form
   has_many :questions, :through => :form
end
```

or with an instant-method:

```
class FormResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form

  def questions
     self.form.questions unless self.form.nil?
  end
end
```

I am not interested in setting questions on FormResponse (I won't need
things like `FormResponse.questions <<` or
`FormResponse.questions.build`), just the fetching.

What are the benefits of using the `has_many :questions, :through =>
:form` over using a method, and vice-versa? Are there benefits like like lazy-loading, better
SQL and so on?

Does AR give any rules of thumb on when to use an AR-relation and when
to simply write your own methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more a question of encapsulation then of ActiveRecord.

In general I would apply I rule of thumb here:

Use `has_many :through` when you actually want to model a relation.

Implement a delegation method when all you want to do is not violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) or keeping your code DRY.